# Browser closes immediately in protractor cucumber test when using cucumberopts format as Json

Tags: json, testing, protractor, cucumber, report

I am running a Protractor cucumber test and trying to generate report using  protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin.

But when I am using format:json:result.json in the config file the browser(chrome) immediately closes as soon as the test starts running and it shows all the test cases passed in the report.

But I wrote the scenarios in such a way that some test cases should fail.This only happens when I using format:json:result.json in cucumberOpts.

When I am using format:'pretty', browser works fine and it shows running of all the test cases and also it shows correct number of test cases passed and failed.

Please find my config file

```
const path = require('path');
exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
         'maths.js',
    ],
    // Tell CucumberJS to save the JSON report
    format: 'json:.tmp/results.json',
    strict: true
},

specs: [
    '*.feature'
],

multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2,
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['disable-infobars']
    }
}],

// Here the magic happens
plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
    options:{
         automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
         removeExistingJsonReportFile: true
    }
}]
```

};

Comment: What Cucumber version are you using?

Comment: cucumber 1.3.2 .I also tried cucumber 2

Comment: Can you add also some step definitions? I assume the issue is in the way you have implemented the steps.

Comment: Please find  my step_definition file in  https://jsfiddle.net/kr66sh6s/1/

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `callback()` function in a step, cucumber runs that step but waits for protractor to finish it.
Protractor runs asynchronously so you have to build the step like:

```
this.Then(/^I title contains angularjs$/, function () {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (text) {
      expect(text).to.eventually.contains('nonAngular');
    })
  });
```

Also you need to add in cucumberOpts:

```
require: "./path/to/step_definition/*.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the conf.js resolved my issue

```
onPrepare: function () {        
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;       
    browser.waitForAngular();           
    browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);       
}
```